# Compile a program and only report if the compilation failed (without showing the errors)

Tags: file, shell, compilation

`$2` has the path to the C file.
The problem is that when I compile a file with errors, it display the errors. I don't want the errors to be displayed, I just want it to say:  "$2 doesn't compile." Any ideas?

```
 cc $2
 if test ! $? = 0              
 then
        echo "$2 doesn't compile."
        exit 1    # exit failure    
 fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress `cc`'s output by redirecting it to `/dev/null`:

```
 if ! cc "$2" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        echo "$2 doesn't compile."
        exit 1    # exit failure    
 fi
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll look more into this.